# Issues with ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED on Lenovo T420

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on multiple Lenovo T420 laptops and installed all the latest updates.

The laptops work flawlessly with Windows 7 Pro.

Once Ubuntu is installed I am able to browse web sites like ebay.com for about 2-3 minutes before I start receiving ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED errors.  This occurs with both Firefox and Chrome.  Not all web sites exhibit this behaviour.  eBay and Shutterfly are two which come to mind.

I have tried the internal Intel Centrino-N 6205 wireless card as well as a USB Alfa (Realtek) wireless adapter.

The only way to get past this is to clear the browser cache.  However, in 2-3 minutes I am back in the same place with ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED errors.  Since this happens on multiple machines and with different wifi cards I can only conclude this is not a driver or wifi adapter issue.

The ability of a clear cache to allow normal functionality leads me to believe there is a clue there somewhere.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A tangential question may be how to ensure the latest Realtek driver is installed on the machine?

Comment: The above comment should say Intel driver not Realtek.